# I am hoping to convert my strings from inputs to the following respective data types. However I keep getting a 'string index out of range' error

Tags: python

```
newtrade = input("Please enter a ticker, buy/sell (b/s), quantity of stock(must be positive), dollar value of stock and date (yyyy-mm-dd format)")
newtradelist = newtrade.split(',')
for value in newtradelist:
    value[2] = int(value[2])
    value[3] = float(value[3])
    value[4] = datetime.strptime(value[4], "%Y-%m-%d")
    newtradelist.append(value)
       

print(newtradelist)
```

If my input is for example abn, b, 1000, 1000, 2020-02-02

given I am splitting these points by ','. Why am I getting an IndexError: string index out of range?

Comment: Why do you use a loop? Seems like you are only converting each element once... When you do `for value in newtradelist` then the `value` variable will get, for example the value of `abn`. Then there is no indexes over 2. Just remove the loop...

Answer (score 0):

correct code

```
newtrade = input("Please enter a ticker, buy/sell (b/s), quantity of stock(must be positive), dollar value of stock and date (yyyy-mm-dd format)")
newtradelist = newtrade.split(',')
newtradelist[2] = int(newtradelist[2].strip(' '))
newtradelist[3] = float(newtradelist[3].strip(' '))
newtradelist[4] = datetime.strptime(newtradelist[4].strip(' '), "%Y-%m-%d")
       

print(newtradelist)
```

I recommend to start from [basics](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_array_loop.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now when i put, '2020-02-02' it says that it does not match the date format as listed above? Any idea why that is?

Comment: In fact, it was because I added spaces, however now the output of the list is this. Why is that? 
['abn', 'b', 1000, 1000.0, datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2, 0, 0)]

Comment: @LucasBlatchford what output you expected to see?

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = 'ab'
 x[2]
 IndexError: string index out of range
```

This produces the same error you described, your string is not long enough to assess the specified element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @rzlmmp's code correction and providing some explanation of what went wrong:
When iterating over the elements of `newtradelist` as you did:

```py
for value in newtradelist:
    value[2] = int(value[2])
    value[3] = float(value[3])
    value[4] = datetime.strptime(value[4], "%Y-%m-%d")
    newtradelist.append(value)
```

Python takes `value` from `newtradelist`. That is, you iterate over the instances `value == "abn"`, `value == "b"`, `value == "1000"`, `value == "1000"`, `value == "2020-02-02"`. So in the first iteration, `value[2]` is `n` (i.e. the third element in `abn`). `value[3]` gives an index error, since `abn` has no fourth letter (it has length `3`).

What you probably want to do is what @rzlvmp suggested in their answer: Take the elements of `newtradelist` with incorrect type (i.e. `newtradelist[2]`, `newtradelist[3]`, and `newtradelist[4]`) and process them accordingly.

What I cannot make sense of is the last line of your `for`-loop. However, @rzlvmp's code does what you probably want without this last line.